# How can one change the meta data in a tiff file using VB or C# to be able to rescale a 3d Terrian data?

Tags: c#, vb.net, terrain, geotiff

The problem is that I have terrain data on sphere about its South Pole in (long,lat,height) format. I would like to translate that data to another sphere (different radius) about its equator and re-scale in terms of the ranges for longitude, latitude and height so that commercial software for cell phones can use it.

If I can read the meta data and the format of the data matrix, I should be able to replace the meta data to be able to translate and scale the data matrix.

We have tried to import it into various commercial software program that does handle terrain data, like System Tool Kit and have asked them to help. So far no luck. We have an approach from Applied Physics Lab to to the procedure, but we don't know how to read the individual data in the Tiff file. I am assuming we need to first read the labels for the meta data and the values associated with the label and get out the pointers for the records so we re-write that record without touching the other records in the file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [TiffBitmapDecoder Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.tiffbitmapdecoder) to read the [BitmapMetadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapmetadata). With the Metadata object you can use [GetQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapmetadata.getquery) to extract metadata and [SetQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapmetadata.setquery) to write metadata from/to a bitmap image file.